# How to read a text file of numbers line by line and store it into an array in C?

Tags: c

I have to read a text file full of numbers and store each number into a string array then display it. Eventually I want to convert the numbers into integers but for now I just want to put them into a string array. My program displays only half the numbers along with a bunch of unwanted empty lines. Here's what I have so far:

```
void displayArray (char *a, int j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", a[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char temp[3];
    char str[26][3];
    int i = 0;

    // open file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    // access file
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(temp, 26, fp);
        //puts(temp);
        strcpy(str[i], temp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    displayArray(str, 26);

    return 0;
}
```

The data file is:

```
8
2
0
10
.5
3
7
3
7
12
12
12
12
1
10
.5
12
12 
12
12
7
3
7
3
```

Comment: `char temp[3]; .... fgets(temp, 26, fp);` --> Code says `temp` is size 26 when it is only 3. Use `fgets(temp, sizeof temp, fp);` and check its return value rather than `feof()`.

Comment: You need to trim the `\n` character after `fgets`. [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)...and what @chux said.

Comment: You are passing `26` to `displayArray(str, 26)` but the lines in `data.txt` may be less than 26. Instead, you should pass `i` ->  `displayArray(str, i)`

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You have two primary problems, (1) the column width in `str` is not sufficient to hold `1, 0, \n, \0` that would be required by `10`. While you will read `1, 0, \0`, the `'\n'` will remain unread in your input stream. To correct the issue, increase the column width.

(never be stingy with buffer size, if you think you may read 3-4 chars, declare a buffer of `8` or so)

Second, you fail to remove the trailing `'\n'` read and included in `str[x]` by default. (all *line-oriented* functions, e.g. `fgets` and POSIX `getline` read and include the `'\n'` in the buffer they fill. Trimming a newline is simple. Get the length, check the last char if the last char in the buffer is `'\n'` by checking `str[n][length-1]`. If it is a `'\n'`, the remove it by overwriting with the *nul-terminating* character, e.g.

```
    /* read each line up to MAXL lines */
    while (n < MAXL && fgets (str[n], MAXC, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (str[n]);   /* get length */
        long tmp;       /* tmp value for conversion */
        errno = 0;      /* reset errno before each conversion     */
        if (len && str[n][len-1] == '\n')   /* is last char '\n'? */
            str[n][--len] = 0;         /* overwrite with nul-char */
        else {           /* the string was too long, handle error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: value at line %d too long.\n", n);
            return 1;
        }
```

(**note:** you also have the benefit of confirming if the line was too-long for the buffer if the last char was not `'\n'`)

Next, you fail to validate the return of `fgets`. The read could fail and you still try and copy `temp`, e.g. (`strcpy(str[i], temp);`). You must validate ALL user input or you can have no confidence you are not simply processing garbage from that point on.

You can use `strtol` to convert your string to a `long`. Use a temporary `long` for the return from `strtol`, then, after checking `errno` to validate the conversion, you can validate the number returned is within the range of valid integers before assigning it to your integer array, e.g.

```
        tmp = strtol (str[n], NULL, BASE);  /* convert to long */
        if (errno) {                        /* validate conversion */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion to int failed '%s'.\n",
                    str[n]);
            return 1;
        }   /* validate in integer range */
        if (tmp < INT_MIN || tmp > INT_MAX) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error arr[%ld] exceeds range of int.\n", 
                    tmp);
            return 1;
        }
        arr[n++] = tmp; /* assign converted & validated value to array */
```

Putting it altogether, you can read your file (or from `stdin`), store the values read as strings and convert the strings to integer values with something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

enum { MAXC = 8, BASE = 10, MAXL = 26 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 0,                      /* array index */
        arr[MAXL] = {0};            /* array of integers */
    char str[MAXL][MAXC] = {""};    /* array of strings */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line up to MAXL lines */
    while (n < MAXL && fgets (str[n], MAXC, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (str[n]);   /* get length */
        long tmp;       /* tmp value for conversion */
        errno = 0;      /* reset errno before each */
        if (len && str[n][len-1] == '\n')   /* is last char '\n'? */
            str[n][--len] = 0;         /* overwrite with nul-char */
        else {           /* the string was too long, handle error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: value at line %d too long.\n", n);
            return 1;
        }
        tmp = strtol (str[n], NULL, BASE);  /* convert to long */
        if (errno) {                        /* validate conversion */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion to int failed '%s'.\n",
                    str[n]);
            return 1;
        }   /* validate in integer range */
        if (tmp < INT_MIN || tmp > INT_MAX) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error arr[%ld] exceeds range of int.\n", 
                    tmp);
            return 1;
        }
        arr[n++] = tmp; /* assign converted & validated value to array */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* output both string and ints */
        printf ("str[%2d] : %-3s    arr[%2d] : %3d\n",
                i, str[i], i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cnvstrtoint < ../dat/numdata.txt
str[ 0] : 8      arr[ 0] :   8
str[ 1] : 2      arr[ 1] :   2
str[ 2] : 0      arr[ 2] :   0
str[ 3] : 10     arr[ 3] :  10
str[ 4] : .5     arr[ 4] :   0
str[ 5] : 3      arr[ 5] :   3
str[ 6] : 7      arr[ 6] :   7
str[ 7] : 3      arr[ 7] :   3
str[ 8] : 7      arr[ 8] :   7
str[ 9] : 12     arr[ 9] :  12
str[10] : 12     arr[10] :  12
str[11] : 12     arr[11] :  12
str[12] : 12     arr[12] :  12
str[13] : 1      arr[13] :   1
str[14] : 10     arr[14] :  10
str[15] : .5     arr[15] :   0
str[16] : 12     arr[16] :  12
str[17] : 12     arr[17] :  12
str[18] : 12     arr[18] :  12
str[19] : 12     arr[19] :  12
str[20] : 7      arr[20] :   7
str[21] : 3      arr[21] :   3
str[22] : 7      arr[22] :   7
str[23] : 3      arr[23] :   3
```

**note:** the integer conversion of `.5` above results in `0`, so if you need to store floating point values, you must declare the array to hold the converted values to `double` or `float` and use a floating-point conversion like `strtod` for the conversion.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Handling non-long integer Lines**

As you have found, depending on your implementation, `strtol` may not accept and truncate `.5` to *zero*, instead it may set `errno`. You have the flexibility to handle a failed conversion any way you choose. For example, if you want to assign `0` manually on a failed conversion and keep the index consistent with the number of lines read, you can *warn* on the failed conversion and manually assign `0`, e.g.

```
    if (errno) {                        /* validate conversion */
        /* if you want to assing zero on a failed conversion, warn */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: conversion to int failed '%s' - "
                "assigning 0.\n", str[n]);
        tmp = 0;
    }
```

(output is the same)

On the other hand, if you simply want to skip any values that are not converted by `strtol`, you can simply *warn* and `continue` (the line having already been read by `fgets`, continuing just advances to the next line in the file):

```
    if (errno) {                        /* validate conversion */
        /* if you want to skip the value entirely, just continue */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: conversion to int failed '%s' - "
                "skipping.\n", str[n]);
        continue;
    }   /* validate in integer range */
```

**Example Use/Output (skipping non-long integer values**

```
$ ./bin/cnvstrtoint < ../dat/numdata.txt
str[ 0] : 8      arr[ 0] :   8
str[ 1] : 2      arr[ 1] :   2
str[ 2] : 0      arr[ 2] :   0
str[ 3] : 10     arr[ 3] :  10
str[ 4] : 3      arr[ 4] :   3
str[ 5] : 7      arr[ 5] :   7
str[ 6] : 3      arr[ 6] :   3
str[ 7] : 7      arr[ 7] :   7
str[ 8] : 12     arr[ 8] :  12
str[ 9] : 12     arr[ 9] :  12
str[10] : 12     arr[10] :  12
str[11] : 12     arr[11] :  12
str[12] : 1      arr[12] :   1
str[13] : 10     arr[13] :  10
str[14] : 12     arr[14] :  12
str[15] : 12     arr[15] :  12
str[16] : 12     arr[16] :  12
str[17] : 12     arr[17] :  12
str[18] : 7      arr[18] :   7
str[19] : 3      arr[19] :   3
str[20] : 7      arr[20] :   7
str[21] : 3      arr[21] :   3
```

Look things over a second time and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It is not working for me. It keeps giving me error: conversion to int failed '%s'.\n cause of .5. or it closes my console for some reason. But i do understand a lot of it now. Thank you! I'm actually trying to do this without worrying about converting to integer I just want it in a string array. Also how do validate fgets exactly and how are you incrementing n?

Comment: That's a possibility. What OS? You see `.5` isn't an integer, and certain implementation will not simply truncate to `zero`. I'll drop an addition and show you how to handle it without exiting.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `while(!feof(fp))` does not work: `feof(fp)` returns true after an attempt at reading the file has failed. Use `fgets()` and check the return value. `NULL` indicates an end of file or a read error.
- `char str[3]` is too short to accommodate for a 2 digit number as the newline is also stored into the destination array.  Make this array much larger.
- your program would have undefined behavior if the file has more than 26 lines. You should either test the nuber of lines or reallocate the destination array.
- the output loop has an incorrect prototype and implementation: it should be:

  ```
  void displayArray(char a[][3], int j) {
      for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
          printf("%s\n", a[i]);
      }
  }
  ```

Here is a naive approach to reading a string array of arbitrary length:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[100];
    char *array = NULL;
    size_t i, count = 0;
    FILE *fp = stdin;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1],
                    strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * (count + 2));
        array[count++] = strdup(buf);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- there is still a limit of 98 bytes for the maximum line length handled by this code.
- memory allocation failure should be tested and reported.
- if the goal is to read numbers, the conversion should probably take place in the reading loop, to avoid useless complications.